# SSRS Data source Credentials and creating a new dataset with existing datascource

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to customize account overview SSRS report, I need some extra fields which don't exists in default data set provided, when I tried creating a new dataset writing a simple query it alerted me to test the datasource connection first.

[image]

When I test for Data Source Credentials; I tried login with my sql server, CRM, and windows credentials. It still doesn't let me in. Any thoughts on how do I go from here ?
[image]

Comment: Did you check the connection string details? Is it pointing to the correct database?

Comment: Hi, its pointing to the right shared database, also if I edit the existing account overview form by adding and removing fields it reflects in the CRM system. I don't know, what would be the credentials its asking for while creating a new data set. I tried with all my credentials.

Comment: Can you double click on your data source (MSCRM_DataSource) and a post a screenshot of the properties without sensitive information?